# How to create a distance from road raster without using Euclidean Distance tool in ArcMap 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, distance

I have created a set of polyline roads as a shapefile, and I would like to create a raster file which shows distance from the nearest road. However, I do not have access to the Euclidean Distance tool so cannot use this. Are there any other suggestions?

I tried buffering the lines then converting this to a raster but this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it but you will need Advanced License:

1. [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) polygons using roads as template dataset (or by manually specifying fishnet extent) and desired cell width and height.
2. Run [Near](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) tool with fishnet polygons as input and roads as near features.
3. Convert the fishnet to raster with [Feature To Raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-to-raster.htm). Use the `NEAR_DIST` field created in step 2 as input field

If you have a large road network this method will be pretty slow.

[image]